# Why can't I use image_url in my presenter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run image_url from my helper it works.
When I try to run the same line from a presenter file it says NoMethodError for image_url.

```
module Presenters
  class PaymentMethod
    ...


    def logo
      image_url("logo.svg")
    end
  end
end
```

I would like to know why it happens and how can I change it so that I can use this method in the presenter.

Answer (score 0):

`image_url` comes from  `ActionView::Helpers` module.

You shoould include `ActionView::Helpers` module at first, then use `image_url` method.

```
module Presenters
  class PaymentMethod
    include ActionView::Helpers


    def logo
      image_url("logo.svg")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Now image_url returns: "http://localhost:3000/images/visa-logo.svg"
instead of: "http://localhost:3000/assets/visa-logo.svg"

Comment: Can you see the image by the link `localhost:3000/assets/visa-logo.svg`? if rails cannot find the image, it will fall back to `/images/visa-logo.svg`.

Comment: Yes I can see it, and it works when this method is in the helper.